# aspx page not working after move it to subfolder

Tags: asp.net, subdirectory

I have a folder named Pages in a visual studio 2010 Project. When I moved an existing "Home.aspx" page to this folder, It is not working while debugging. Any idea, Why this happens ?

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean? What specifically is happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see on your image that you have Master Pages.

The basic reason to not working after you move it - is to not find his Master Page that is probably connected with.

Maybe there are more reasons - like to not find other custom controls that are connected to it.